# Can Android and iPhone communicate over bluetooth SPP profile?

Tags: android, ios, bluetooth, spp

Android and iPhone communicate over bluetooth SPP profile ? Can huge data communication possible ? Can't use BLE.

Answer (score 0):

No. Apps on iOS do not have access to SPP except to communicate with MFi certified accessories.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response. So as per your answer is it possible with MFi certified accessories? Means hardware with MFi chip? Can you please elaborate how it can be done over MFi certified accessories? There is one android hardware currently I will get back to you with that hardware device details .

Comment: Mfi accessories are accessed through the External Accessory framework; full details are provided by Apple when you join the MFi program.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the info. MFi is for SPP communication for iOS devices. Problem statement is communicating between iOS devices and Android devices , so will it be possible over MFi? I have android development work experience I am very much new to iOS , just now started exploring.

Comment: I doubt that MFi will help you; Android devices are not going to contain the MFi chip.  You would probably be better off looking at WiFi

Comment: Over WiFi it's working now the requirement is to communicate over SPP.

Comment: That isn't going to be possible on iOS.

Comment: Ok....Is it possible by running Android APK on Mac machine and through that communicating with iOS devices?

Comment: You would still have to use wifi or BLE to communicate to the iOS device from the Mac.  You can transfer files to an iOS app using iTunes