# How to send serial data to a mac using the bluetooth serial profile

Tags: iphone, macos, bluetooth, serial-port, macos-high-sierra

I'm working on software that must receive and parse serial data sent over an rs232 connection. My macbook (running macOS High Sierra) doesn't have a physical serial port, but it does have a port listed as "Bluetooth-Incoming-Port". To my understanding, data can be sent to this port via bluetooth and received just as if it had been sent over a cable. I would like to send data (ASCII text) from my iphone to this port to test my software, but I can't figure out how to do this - all the tutorials I've found are oriented towards arduino setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it seems you can't, according to this post from Apple forum:  [iOS support for SPP Bluetooth](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8326568).  Also, [this from stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42825417/can-android-and-iphone-communicate-over-bluetooth-spp-profile), which mentions MFi accessories, which is the only "bluetooth classic" support allowed for iPhones.